# Redirect url for Microsoft RD Web (Server 2012)

Tags: rewrite, windows-server-2012, url, rds, iis-8

I have installed RD Web on the same web server as `OWA` and `ECP` (Exch 2013) console.

All web applications are installed in the `Default Web Site` and `Exchange Back End`

For `OWA` and `ActiveSync` my users connects to `https://mail.domain.com/owa`

As for now, in order to access RD Web my users have to connect to `https://mail.domain.com/rdweb`

I want this adress to be `https://remote.domain.com`

Would this be possible even though the web applications are installed under the same web site in IIS?

I have registered the records for both `remote` and `mail` in my DNS so they point to the same IP. I also have a trusted UCC SSL Cert for both names.

The webserver is `IIS 8` can I use `URL Rewrite`? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iis7 and 2008r2 I did something similar: made sure site answers to the proper binding, then used a redirect 301 rule, two of them actually one on the main site then one on rdweb sub site:

```
main site:
redirect to: https://remote.blah.com/rdweb
redirect all requests to exact dest.
perm 301

rdweb subsite:
redirect to: /RDWeb/Pages/default.aspx
Only Redirect Requests to content in this directory
perm 301
```

I should note that I have a cname of remote.blah.com pointing to my server, the first redirect simply forces https and adds the /rdweb peice

hope this helps!

also, from what I recall Exchange was recommended to be on its own box.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Set-OWAVirtualDirectory`

```
Set-OWAVirtualDirectory –Identity “owa (default web site)” -InternalURL https:myinternalname.com/owa -ExternalURL https://mynewdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to have both Exchange 2013 and RD web working on the same server ?????

When I install remote desktop on exchange 2013 everything is broken: OWA; ECP and RDW

Comment: There was no problem for me, I added RDWeb through server manager after I installed Exchange 2013.

Answer (score 0):

OK

What is the procedure:

Exchange 2013 installed

Then Add role
Remote Desktop Services installation
Quick start
Session based

After the reboot ... 
The exchange shell can't connect to exchange ... impossible to set owa

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should start your own question :)

Comment: As a possible answer to your question, check to see if both the Default Website and Exchange Back End are running. I know, when adding TS Gateway - it automatically adds a 443 binding to the backend site wich makes it impossible for the default site to run, as it require the port 443 to run.